# Is there anyway to set the default admin url from oracle apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I've installed an oracle apex environment and everything is okay, but my root URL open the admin page and i like to open the application itself. Where i can change it?

For example:

- http://my-url.com -> open app
- http://my-url.com/apex/admin -> open the admin

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you meant to run Apex (development tool) so that it automatically opens one of applications within that workspace (so that you could develop it further), I don't think that you can do that.

- run Apex first (credentials require workspace, username and password)
- go to App Builder
- choose application (because, one workspace can contain many applications)
- work on it

---

However, if your question is how to actually *run* desired application without going into Apex (development tool) first, navigating to the application and then running it, then a simple option is to do exactly that:

- go to Apex, go to App Builder, run desired application
- in browser's address line you'll see something like this:

  ```
  https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=12488
  ```

  This is my application whose APP_ID = 12488, stored on online apex.oracle.com, but never mind that - you'd just **bookmark** that URL and then - whenever you want to run it - choose that bookmark from the list (or the toolbar, depending on where you put it).

Comment: I *think* there is something that can be changed in networking land to make this happen, but I'm not sure how/what. Perhaps an ORDS configuration https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4299960/redirect-to-apex-application-if-i-enter-url-in-browser-address